# QGIS Time manager raster error

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I would like to give a shot to the Time manager in QGIS with some raster datasets.

I load 2 rasters (both single band, 32bit float).

I add the first one in the Time Manager window with the start date: 2008-01-01 / end date: 2008-01-31 , it s fine.
Then I add the second one with the start date: 2008-02-01 / end date: 2008-02-31.

After I enter the second one I have got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/b/.qgis2/python/plugins\timemanager\vectorlayerdialog.py", line 70, in add_layer_to_table
settings  = self.extract_settings()
File "C:/Users/b/.qgis2/python/plugins\timemanager\rasterlayerdialog.py", line 24, in extract_settings
return ls.getSettingsFromAddRasterLayersUI(self.dialog, self.tempLayerIndexToId)
File "C:/Users/b/.qgis2/python/plugins\timemanager\layer_settings.py", line 77, in getSettingsFromAddRasterLayersUI
result.layerId =  layerIndexToId[ui.comboBoxLayers.currentIndex()]
KeyError: 2
```

Anyone has already seen this error?

ps: I use QGIS 2.8.1